# Know the Jenkins build status of a build with particular build number

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Using Jenkins groovy API how to know the status of a build whether it's success or failure .

I have a job in https://localhost.com/Jenkins/Mano/Dev/parallel/123

Where parallel is the job name and 123 is its build number . And the job is residing inside Mano/Dev folder .

I'd like to know the status of the Job with build number 123 .

Is there any direct API call to find the status

Any help is highly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins got a REST api, if you open your jobs page, select your build, visit the *REST api* link in the bottom right. Its quite self explanatory, i.e. to get the result in json: `http://<junkins url>/job/<job name>/<build #>/api/json?tree=result`